# convert string array to float MEL

Tags: maya, mel

I having a trouble with a code in MAYA 2020.

- I want to create a new expression  into a default value  of a  Arnold `aiUserDataInt`
- I need the default value of a `aiUserDataInt = attribute` from a geometry that I crate name `"ID"`

so, my code looks like this:

```
string $Selected[] = `ls -selection`;

for ($node in $Selected)

aiUserDataInt1.default = $Selected.id;
```

but I have these error:

> // Error: Line 2.37: Cannot cast data of type string[] to float. //

So, I suppose default value do not accept arrays

my question would be: is there a way to convert array into float?

*or* what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's not how mel works. You can do:

```
string $Selected[] = `ls -selection`;
for ($node in $Selected)
{
   int $id = getAttr($node + ".id");
   setAttr("aiUserDataInt1.default", $id);
}
```

Didn't test it, but it should work like this. You get and set attributes with getAttr() and setAttr().

Comment: Hi tnks for the answer, but Unfortunately, that code get an error:  // Error: line 3: No object matches name: aiUserDataInt1.id // 
// Error: line 0: An execution error occured in the expression expression3. // 
// Result: expression3 // 
sorry I´m a newbie programing

Comment: If you get this error, you selected the aiUserDataInt1 node and executed the script. You have to select your object and exectute the script.